# How to render a menu with Razor using an Editor-Template?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razorengine, modelmetadata

I have an asp.net core 3.1 based app. I like to utilize Display-Templates and Editor-Templates to create the editor views. I am trying to figure out the best approach on how to create editor templates for menus using editor-templates.

My first thought is to create a generic view-model for for menus which then can easily be rendered using a custom editor-template

In a first attempt, I Created a generic viewmodel that looks like this

```
public abstract class MenuViewModel
{
    [BindNever]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

    public MenuViewModel()
    {
        Options = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}

public class MenuViewModel<T> : MenuViewModel
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am hoping to use it in other view-models like this

```
public class CreateLocation
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public MenuViewModel<string> State { get; set; }
}
```

I think I can get the above code working... However, I am trying to figure out a way to pass any `ValiationAttributes` from the `State` property down to the `State.Value` property instead.

For example, what if the `State` is decorated with `RequiredAttribute`? In other words, what if my view-model looks like this

```
public class CreateLocation
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public MenuViewModel<string> State { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, for the model-state to be valid the `State` Property cannot be null and the property `State.Value` must also have a value..

Question is, how can I pass my required attribute down to the `Value` property without having to create multiple menu-vm like `RequiredMenuViewModel` and `OptionalMenuViewModel`?

I thought about creating an implementation of the `IDisplayMetadataProvider`. But even then, I am not sure how to pass the validation attribute from the parent property to the child.

```
public class MenuMetadataProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Key.ModelType.IsClass)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(context.Key.ModelType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MenuViewModel)))
        {
            metadata.TemplateHint = nameof(MenuViewModel);
        }

        // get any validation attributes on the parent
        var attributes = context.Key.ModelType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), false);

        if (!attributes.Any())
        {
            // Parent has not attributes, ignore it
            return;
        }

        // iterate over the properties of the child object
        foreach (PropertyInfo childPoperty in context.Key.ModelType.GetProperties())
        {
            // find a child property that is decorated with InheritAttributesFromParentAttribute
            var canInherit = Attribute.IsDefined(childPoperty, typeof(InheritAttributesFromParent));

            if (!canInherit)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // some how pass the attributes to the childPoperty
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this [answer](https://forums.asp.net/t/2169055.aspx?How+to+use+editor+templates+from+within+a+razor+page+that+resides+in+an+area+) help you?